# Get moon location with respect to the current location (using a GPS and accelerometer) on Earth

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer, astronomy

I found [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ratana.sunsurveyor&hl=en). It finds the Sun in the sky using the GPS and accelerometer. Here is shot of its professional version:

[image: App detecting sun path and current location in the Sky]

So as you can see, in this screen it's detecting the moons current position and path in the sky, when user point it in the sky. It uses the camera as background and above it places the Moon's image.

So now, I have almost zero experience in astrophysics. I don't know about desired input, etc., but the output could be (latitude, longitude) and the accelerometer position with respect to Earth, so I could place the Moon on the camera when the devices GPS and accelerometer match with the result.

Apart from the above, I've found [this tool](http://www.satellite-calculations.com/Satellite/suncalc.htm), but I really don't know which value to use and how to use it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an application, not a programming related question.

Comment: No it is not, if you read it again I am asking for the algorithm used by this app and if you know algorithms are base of programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need the position on earth and the current time to calculate where the moon should be seen; then, when you add the orientation of the phone (camera), you can determine where on the captured image the moon must be drawn. For this, you will need the compass to determine the orientation on the earth's surface, plus data from the accelerometer to find the elevation angle at which the device looks at the sky.

I guess you won't really need too much astronomics for this, but you will definitely need a formula or database yielding the expected relative position of earth/moon at any given time. This can probably be found on the internet pretty easily.